# Minimal Example of Unreal Engine’s QoS Plugin

Tags: c++, networking, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, qos

Unreal Engine has Quality Of Service plugin, however I don’t really see any examples of how it is used in the anywhere in the code or any documentation beyond the member functions, so I don’t know how to have the game client actually use it. Assuming a valid set of servers capable of receiving QoS requests, what is a minimal example of how to use the plugin for the game client? Do you have to write your own net driver?

https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/API/Plugins/Qos/